# python script to automate transferring data into CAN messages for CANblue V2 from IXAAT using python-can module

Tags: python, python-3.x, scripting, embedded, python-can

I have a question like ... we have some data files with messages for microcontroller . We use Blue CAN v2 [IXXAT] [https://www.ixxat.com/products/products-industrial/can-interfaces/usb-can-interfaces/usb-to-can-v2-professional?ordercode=1.01.0281.12001]    with  simulator to transfer messages to microcontroller . we are doing through GUI ,can we use some module in pythonto write a script to automate it .

I have read about CANpy module ...But not able to get the proper information regarding that.

Can anyone help regarding this ... i am bit new to embedded environment and python

Does this flow work :
installing python-can module in windows
settting interface and channel before exporting data
using can.player module
python -m can.player -i ixxat

Comment: You can use link formatter to add hyperlinks in a proper way.

Comment: Use this link for more details about editing: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help